# How to implement a Tmux like session windows in Golang

Tags: go, terminal, tmux

I am working on a project using Golang. I would like to implement a feature that is similar to tmux session windows. The following features is what I look for:

1. Tmux sessions (persistent session not required)
2. A bottom bar showing the current sessions
3. Switching between the sessions

I tried to use tmux session managers written in Golang but those ultimately use tmux underneath.

I would like any ideas on how to proceed with this. The main thing I would like to know to how make the bottom bar and switching between sessions(sort of) or a simple tmux clone in Golang

Comment: i'd suggest you take a look at tmux's source code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.